# How can i replace the value of checked radio button from a LIST whenever i change my option from yes to no vice versa in UWP

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, mobile, uwp

// This is for both radio button on the list, when i change mind to click option yes instead of no, it adds another value to the list instead of changing the value of the answer in the list from 0 t0 1 or 1 to 0

```
private void Service_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
            if (rb != null)
            {
                string answer = rb.Content.ToString();
                switch (answer)
                {
                    case "Yes":
                        value = 1;
                        break;
                    case "No":
                        value = 0;
                        break;
                }
            }
            int RID = int.Parse(rb.DataContext.ToString());
            Questionnaire you = new Questionnaire();
            you.id = RID;
            you.answer = value;
            selectedItems.Add(you);
        }
```

// When selecting the submit button

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            refno.id = txtRefNo.Text;
            string comment = txtComment.Text;

            Rootobjectsssss ratingClass = new Rootobjectsssss()
            {
                description = comment,
                booking = refno,
                rating = rating,
                questionnaire = selectedItems.ToArray(),
            };

            json = string.Empty;
            json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ratingClass, Formatting.Indented);
            Debug.WriteLine(json);
        }
```

// Where i get my ID that is binded to both radio button

```
async void getData()
        {
            string url = "http://62.173.41.5:7500/NNRAService/webresources/customerResources/getQuestionaire";
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
            var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JsonArray root = JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetArray();
            for (uint i = 0; i < root.Count; i++)
            {
                string Question = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedString("question");
                string Id = root.GetObjectAt(i).GetNamedNumber("id").ToString();
                var chan = new Class1
                {
                    question = Question,
                    id = Id,

                };
                feedbackList.Add(chan);
            };
            feedbackListView.ItemsSource = feedbackList;

        }
```

// My Xalm code, it contains the listview and my radio button, i binded the Id to both buttons

```
<ListView Margin="10,0,10,20" Background="White" x:Name="feedbackListView">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Rootobject">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding question}"></TextBlock>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <RadioButton DataContext="{Binding id}" Foreground="Green" Name="ServiceYes" Content="Yes"  Tag="Yes"  Checked="Service_Checked" ></RadioButton>
                                    <RadioButton DataContext="{Binding id}" Foreground="Red" Name="ServiceNo" Content="No" Tag="No"  Checked="Service_Checked"></RadioButton>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ListView>
```

// My Model Class

```
public class Class1
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string question { get; set; }
    }


    public class Rootobjectsssss
    {
        public string description { get; set; }
        public Boooking booking { get; set; }
        public int rating { get; set; }
        public Questionnaire[] questionnaire { get; set; }
    }

    public class Boooking
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
    }

    public class Questionnaire
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int answer { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are always adding the changedItem to SelectedItem list that's why it adding instead of replacing.

You may need to put a check before adding an item to selectedItems. Something like below:

```
private void Service_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton rb = sender as RadioButton;
        if (rb != null)
        {
            string answer = rb.Content.ToString();
            switch (answer)
            {
                case "Yes":
                    value = 1;
                    break;
                case "No":
                    value = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        int RID = int.Parse(rb.DataContext.ToString());

        Questionnaire temp = selectedItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == RID);
        if(temp == null)
        {
           Questionnaire you = new Questionnaire();
           you.id = RID;
           you.answer = value;
           selectedItems.Add(you);
        }
        else
        {
           temp.answer = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. how can I authenticate it that a user must select either yes or no before submitting. I mean all questions must be answered

Comment: You can always verify the Count in selectedItems list and the total number of questions you have, both count should match. However I feel there must be a better way and it will not be feasible to answer without knowing the design of your solution. Please open another question for your specific problem and add more details to the new question.